# How to parallelize a pandas UDF in polars (h3 polyfill) for string typed UDF outputs?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, python-polars, h3

I want to execute the following lines of python code in Polars as a UDF:

```
w = wkt.loads('POLYGON((-160.043334960938 70.6363054807905, -160.037841796875 70.6363054807905, -160.037841796875 70.6344840663086, -160.043334960938 70.6344840663086, -160.043334960938 70.6363054807905))')
polygon (optionally including holes).
j = shapely.geometry.mapping(w)
h3.polyfill(j, res=10, geo_json_conformant=True)
```

In pandas/geopandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import polars as pl
from shapely import wkt

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'quadkey': {0: '0022133222330023',
  1: '0022133222330031',
  2: '0022133222330100'},
 'tile': {0: 'POLYGON((-160.043334960938 70.6363054807905, -160.037841796875 70.6363054807905, -160.037841796875 70.6344840663086, -160.043334960938 70.6344840663086, -160.043334960938 70.6363054807905))',
  1: 'POLYGON((-160.032348632812 70.6381267305321, -160.02685546875 70.6381267305321, -160.02685546875 70.6363054807905, -160.032348632812 70.6363054807905, -160.032348632812 70.6381267305321))',
  2: 'POLYGON((-160.02685546875 70.6417687358462, -160.021362304688 70.6417687358462, -160.021362304688 70.6399478155463, -160.02685546875 70.6399478155463, -160.02685546875 70.6417687358462))'},
 'avg_d_kbps': {0: 15600, 1: 6790, 2: 9619},
 'avg_u_kbps': {0: 14609, 1: 22363, 2: 15757},
 'avg_lat_ms': {0: 168, 1: 68, 2: 92},
 'tests': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 6},
 'devices': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1}}

)
# display(pandas_df)

gdf = pandas_df.copy()
gdf['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(pandas_df['tile'])

import h3pandas
display(gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(10))
```

This works super quickly and easily.
However, the polyfill function called from pandas apply as a UDF is too slow for the size of my dataset.

Instead, I would love to use polars but I run into several issues:

### geo type is not understood

rying to move to polars for better performance

```
pl.from_pandas(gdf)
```

fails with: ArrowTypeError: Did not pass numpy.dtype object

it looks like geoarrow / geoparquet is not supported by polars

### numpy vectorized polars interface fails with missing geometry types

```
polars_df = pl.from_pandas(pandas_df)
out = polars_df.select(
    [
        gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(pl.col('tile')),
    ]
)
```

fails with:

```
TypeError: 'data' should be array of geometry objects. Use from_shapely, from_wkb, from_wkt functions to construct a GeometryArray.
```

### all by hand

```
polars_df.with_column(pl.col('tile').map(lambda x: h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(wkt.loads(x)), res=10, geo_json_conformant=True)).alias('geometry'))
```

fails with:

```
Conversion of polars data type Utf8 to C-type not implemented.
```

this last option seems to be the most promising one (no special geospatial-type errors). But this generic error message of strings/Utf8 type for C not being implemented sounds very strange to me.

Furthermore:

```
polars_df.select(pl.col('tile').apply(lambda x: h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(wkt.loads(x)), res=10, geo_json_conformant=True)))
```

works - but is lacking the other columns - i.e. syntax to manually select these is inconvenient. Though this is also failing when appending a:

```
.explode('tile').collect()
# InvalidOperationError: cannot explode dtype: Object("object")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address some of your polars errors:

---

The `wkt` functions can't handle a `pl.Series` - you can use `.to_numpy()` to provide a numpy array instead:

```
gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(polars_df.get_column("tile").to_numpy())
```

```
0    POLYGON ((-160.04333 70.63631, -160.03784 70.6...
1    POLYGON ((-160.03235 70.63813, -160.02686 70.6...
2    POLYGON ((-160.02686 70.64177, -160.02136 70.6...
dtype: geometry
```

---

You can use `.with_columns()` instead of `.select()`:

```
polars_df.with_columns(pl.col('tile').apply(lambda x: h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(wkt.loads(x)), res=10, geo_json_conformant=True)))
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ quadkey          | tile                                | avg_d_kbps | avg_u_kbps | avg_lat_ms | tests | devices │
│ ---              | ---                                 | ---        | ---        | ---        | ---   | ---     │
│ str              | object                              | i64        | i64        | i64        | i64   | i64     │
╞══════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 0022133222330023 | {'8a0d1c1306a7fff', '8a0d1c1306b... | 15600      | 14609      | 168        | 2     | 1       │
│ 0022133222330031 | {'8a0d1c130757fff', '8a0d1c13062... | 6790       | 22363      | 68         | 1     | 1       │
│ 0022133222330100 | {'8a0d1c1300d7fff', '8a0d1c1300c... | 9619       | 15757      | 92         | 6     | 1       │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

---

`h3.polyfill()` is returning a python set object which polars does not really "recognize" as it stands.

You can convert the set to `list()` and polars will give you a `list[str]` column instead of `object` - which you can `.explode()` without error.

```
polars_df.with_columns(
   pl.col('tile').apply(lambda x: list(h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(wkt.loads(x)), res=10, geo_json_conformant=True)))
     .alias('h3_polyfill')
).explode('h3_polyfill')
```

```
shape: (9, 8)
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────────────┐
│ quadkey          | tile                                | avg_d_kbps | avg_u_kbps | avg_lat_ms | tests | devices | h3_polyfill     │
│ ---              | ---                                 | ---        | ---        | ---        | ---   | ---     | ---             │
│ str              | str                                 | i64        | i64        | i64        | i64   | i64     | str             │
╞══════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0022133222330023 | POLYGON((-160.043334960938 70.63... | 15600      | 14609      | 168        | 2     | 1       | 8a0d1c1306a7fff │
│ 0022133222330023 | POLYGON((-160.043334960938 70.63... | 15600      | 14609      | 168        | 2     | 1       | 8a0d1c1306b7fff │
│ 0022133222330023 | POLYGON((-160.043334960938 70.63... | 15600      | 14609      | 168        | 2     | 1       | 8a0d1c13079ffff │
│ 0022133222330031 | POLYGON((-160.032348632812 70.63... | 6790       | 22363      | 68         | 1     | 1       | 8a0d1c130757fff │
│ 0022133222330031 | POLYGON((-160.032348632812 70.63... | 6790       | 22363      | 68         | 1     | 1       | 8a0d1c130627fff │
│ 0022133222330031 | POLYGON((-160.032348632812 70.63... | 6790       | 22363      | 68         | 1     | 1       | 8a0d1c13070ffff │
│ 0022133222330100 | POLYGON((-160.02685546875 70.641... | 9619       | 15757      | 92         | 6     | 1       | 8a0d1c1300d7fff │
│ 0022133222330100 | POLYGON((-160.02685546875 70.641... | 9619       | 15757      | 92         | 6     | 1       | 8a0d1c1300c7fff │
│ 0022133222330100 | POLYGON((-160.02685546875 70.641... | 9619       | 15757      | 92         | 6     | 1       | 8a0d1c1300f7fff │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────────────┘
```

---

There's probably not much difference compared to doing the "all by hand" approach in pandas:

```
pandas_df['geometry'] = wkt.loads(pandas_df['tile'])
pandas_df = pandas_df.assign(
   h3_polyfill=pandas_df['geometry'].map(lambda tile: h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(tile), 10, True))
).explode('h3_polyfill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Polars benefits come from the fact that the data is stored in type inflexible arrow2 arrays and that the computations are optimized (similar to a db query optimizer) and run in rust.  Any time you use `apply` in polars then you lose the benefit of polars because it's sending the function back to python instead of it being optimized and computed in rust.  Polars [doesn't support anything that looks like a shapely geometry](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/datatypes.html) nor does it have geospatial geometry operators built in.

There is [geopolars](https://github.com/geopolars/geopolars) which is in its absolute infancy and probably not particularly usable yet.  Long story short, polars (in python) isn't able to help for geo computations yet.

Back to your original problem, what if instead of `gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(10)` you do something like (emphasis on *something like* as I'm not really familiar with `h3` offhand)

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
h3.polyfill(mapping(gdf.geometry))
```

You might need to explore the dict that `mapping(gdf.geometry)` returns to get something conforming to the geojson input that h3 uses.

The idea being that feeding the entire input directly to h3 will (at least potentially, I'm not aware of its internals) allow it to do all the looping and iterating in C rather than having the looping in python which is what you get with an `apply`.

Comment: h3.unstable.vect.* only has geo_to_h3 and some other functions. Not the polyfill one.

Comment: Indeed I would not recommend anyone to use geopolars yet as of Jan 2023 (as the author). There's a package in Rust to connect h3 and polars, but doesn't have python bindings yet https://github.com/nmandery/h3ron/tree/main/h3ron-polars

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I don't know about h3.unstable.vect but [here's](https://nbviewer.org/github/uber/h3-py-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/usage.ipynb) a reference to `h3.polyfill` being used directly.  I don't even know what it does, my point is just that using it directly by feeding it a geojson object directly might be faster than going through the geopandas convenience wrapper.  I genuinely don't know.

Comment: @KyleBarron does that means I should amend that paragraph or is what I wrote is still true

Comment: h3ron-polars does connect h3 and polars. It's not really a problem to link to the h3 C library, and since h3 indexes can be stored as uint64 integers, a column of h3 values can be stored in arrow memory easily. There's also a new pure-rust h3 reimplementation that can avoid linking to the h3 C library https://github.com/HydroniumLabs/h3o